# Unable to pass parameter to export method in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the sample.js :

```
module.exports = (function (param) {
   // I'm expecting param to be available here
})();
```

Here is the app.js

```
var sampleMsg= require('./controller/sample')(param);
app.use('/sample', sampleMsg);
```

But the above code when run throws the following error:

```
D:\Working\GUI\Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.handle (D:\Working\GUI\Server\node_modules\express\lib
\router\index.js:140:27)
    at router (D:\Working\GUI\Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\i
ndex.js:46:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Working\GUI\Server\app.js:267:54)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
(function (param) {
   // I'm expecting param to be available here
})()
```

is a self-invoking function which returns `undefined`. You can't invoke an `undefined` value as it's not a function. Also, in the above code `param` is also `undefined` as the invocation operator (`()`) doesn't pass any parameters to the anonymous function. In the following code `param` is `"I'm the param"` string:

```
(function (param) {
   // ...
})("I'm the param");
```

It not clear why you are using a self-invoking function here. If you need to use a closure the syntax should be:

```
module.exports = function(param) {
   return function(req, res, next) {
      // ...
   }
}
// ...
var routeHandler = require('./controller/sample')(param);
app.use('/sample', routeHandler);
```

Comment: Ok .. is there a way to a init method inside the sample.js ?

Comment: The closure function example in my answer can be used as an initializer, it's a closure function that returns another function. The returned function can be used as an express route handler. Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work